# How do you access Angular scss variables in typescript?

Tags: angular, material-design, elevation

I'm trying to access the theme colors from other places in my app. I can access primary, accent, and warn on material elements using color="primary" but sometimes color isn't an option, like when I want to access the colors programatically. Anyone know how to access the theme variables in other places? I think, more specifically, I'm trying to use an scss variable in either typescript, or a css style, whatever gets the job done, but just get errors when I try to use the variables.